# Cannot get product availability

Tags: magento

I'm trying to display availability in the order confirmation email, that is sent to the client. Anything I've tried so far, is not working:

```
$_order = $this->getOrder();
foreach ($_order->getAllItems() as $_item):

    if ($_item->isSaleable()):
          echo $this->helper('catalog')->__('In stock');
    else:
          echo $this->helper('catalog')->__('Out of stock');
    endif;

endforeach;
```

I've also tried 
$_item->getStockQty();
$_item->isAvailable();

Why is this not working? Could you help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modified code is

```
$_order = $this->getOrder();
foreach ($_order->getAllItems() as $_item):

    if(($_item->getProduct()->getSku()==$_item->getSku()){

    if ($_item->getProduct()->isSaleable()):
              echo $this->helper('catalog')->__('In stock');
        else:
              echo $this->helper('catalog')->__('Out of stock');
        endif;
    }else{

    $product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
    $product->loadByAttribute('sku',$_item->getSku())

    if (($_item->getProduct()->isSaleable()) && ($product->isSaleable()):
              echo $this->helper('catalog')->__('In stock');
        else:
              echo $this->helper('catalog')->__('Out of stock');
        endif;



    }
foreach;
```

Comment: Your code makes sense but it's not working for some reason. It's supposed to display product information in the order confirmation email. But there must be some error in the code, because the email is not sent, when I use your code. I cannot trace the error though....

Comment: The file I editing is the following: app/design/frontend/base/default/template/email/order/items/order/default.phtml. This where I placed your code

Comment: OK, I've found some syntax errors in there, that's what was causing the errors. Thanks anyway!